# Uncaught PHP Exception "Unknown handler dfs" in eZ Publish

Tags: php, symfony, microsoft-distributed-file-system, ezpublish

I'm getting following error in my eZpublish application while fetching the content using:

```
$wrapper->content->getFieldValue('short_name', $currentLanguage)->text;
```

Error:

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException: "Unknown handler dfs" at /var/www/application/releases/v1/wwwroot/vendor/ezsystems/ezpublish-kernel/eZ/Bundle/EzPublishIOBundle/ApiLoader/HandlerFactory.php line 39.
```

Is there any way to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.